# iOS, tvOS: Typography - Fitting Font Size

Tags: ios, swift, font-size, tvos, typography

We have iOS and tvOS targets in the same project. There are same labels in the project but since their screen size's is different, labels' font sizes' need to be different. I am here to ask what is the best approach for this. Does the given example fine?

```
let font = UIFont(name: name, size: UIApplication.OS == .iOS ? 16 : 24)
```

Or maybe I am missing some exist Apple product or tool that are already done this.
Also, is there any rate to calculate the appropriate font size for tvOS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have font sizes that are accessible  (fixed font sizes are generally a bad idea because people have different accessibility preferences), you may want to look into supporting Dynamic Type:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically

Comment: Yes, thanks for answer. Actually, we already use dynamic type but it is just performed in iOS platform not for tvOS, what I mean it is not going to be bigger in tvOS, it stays in 16.